# What do these numbers mean in ElasticSearch head?

Tags: elasticsearch

In the Overview tab of my ElasticSearch head it shows the following:

stock
size: 2.2gb (2.2gb)
docs: 1062049 (1598589)

Can someone tell me what the 2 docs numbers 1062049 and 1598589 mean?

Answer (score 19):

The first number is `num_docs`, the second number is `max_docs`.  Both are provided by the [Index Status API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-status.html)

- `num_docs` is simple: it is the number of documents living inside your index at this moment
- `max_docs` is a bit more nebulous, I believe it is the max docs your index has seen before a merge removed the deleted docs.  It also includes nested documents, which internally are a new doc but appear as a single doc to the end-user

Comment: why are there 2 different sizes? 2.2 (2.2)

Comment: @HenleyChiu The first number is the size of the index, the second is the size of the index + size of all replicas.

Comment: @Zach Hypothetically, if there are 10 docs and I deleted 2 docs, the num_docs is 8 and max_docs is 10. I cannot make sense what did you mean. It is not relevant with replicas in terms of "Delete" portion.

Comment: Actually it seems that the docs numbers are the number of docs in the primary nodes vs all the nodes including replicas. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html for more details. Basically, according to the docs, "The stats returned are aggregated on the index level, with primaries and total aggregations, where primaries are the values for only the primary shards, and total are the cumulated values for both primary and replica shards."

Answer (score 1):

The value without brackets shows us **sum of sizes of primary shards**.

The value inside brackets shows us **sum of sizes of primary shards + sum of sizes of replica shards**.

In your case, you've only 1 primary shard and 0 replica shards. So, it shows you index size 2.2 GB (2.2 GB).

***Similar convention is followed for the document count.***

I hope this helps.